# Connect to RabbitMQ from PHP - Windows

Tags: php, windows-7, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ running on one of our servers and am trying to connect to it via PHP. I am developing on a Windows7 machine and my first line of code reads:
$cnn = new AMQPConnection();

It gives me the error:
**Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found in**

I know that it is something that I need to install but what is it ? I am new to PHP so a little help would be nice.

Ps: I can connect to the RMQ server via the RabbitMQ admin web interface.

Thank you
Jack

Comment: The answer you accepted is no longer correct. `RabbitMQ` and also `amqp` are now available for Windows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am developing on a Windows7 machine

You may be out of luck using that specific code.  That class is from the [PECL aqmp extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp).  Inside [the installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/amqp.installation.php), it states:

> Note to Windows users: This extension does not currently support Windows since the [librabbitmq](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) library does not yet support Windows.

You will want to use [another library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4405992/168868) to speak to your message queue instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What other library will you recommend I use on Windows?

Comment: No idea, as neither running PHP on Windows nor using RabbitMQ are my thing.  I prefer Gearman.  ;)  Any library written in pure-PHP should work fine for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Installation guide for php_amqp 1.4.0 (Stable version):**

1. Download proper package for your php version from https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.4.0/windows
2. Unpack php_amqp.dll to X:/php/ext/ directory
3. Unpack rabbitmq.1.dll to X:/Windows/system (not system32) directory
4. Modify php.ini file and add "extension=php_amqp.dll" line at the end of extensions list
5. Verify module installation by executing command "X:/php/php.exe -m" in command line
6. Restart webserver

Answer (score 1):

The rabbitmq-c library supports windows now, and the php_amqp pecl extension builds on windows as well.  The documentation just hasn't been updated, nor are there any official binary builds in the wild.  However, I managed to get them to build and have some 32 bit dll's available for download here:

http://www.nathanjohnson.info/?p=77

Answer (score 0):

@ [AMQP installation php.net](http://php.net/manual/fa/amqp.installation.php):

> Note to Windows users: This extension does not currently support Windows since the librabbitmq library does not yet support Windows.

But [here at RabbitMQ website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html) is a windows installer...

Apparently this **php.net** page is **outdated**

---

### To install do like this:

1. Download the correct package for your php from [this official PECL amqp 1.4.0 page](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.4.0/windows)
2. unzip
3. add `amqp.dll` to your php `ext` folder
4. add `rabbitmq.1.dll` to your windows system 32 folder.

This according to the post on the blog I found [here](http://www.nathanjohnson.info/?p=77) i think it is from the same @NathanJohnson who posted also here.

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working:

```
My System Config: Win 7 Pro, (x64) XAMPP running PHP 5.6(x86)
```

Follow instruction from here to install RabbitMQ:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html

Now download compatible extension from here

https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.4.0/windows

in my case it is "5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86"

Now from zip file (php_amqp-1.4.0-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip) downloaded copy dll "php_amqp.dll" to your php extension folder in my case it is "xampp/php/ext" and copy dll "rabbitmq.1.dll" to "Windows\system" directory.

now register your php_amqp dll in php.ini file as 
"extension=php_amqp.dll"

now restart apache.

Done. Now you should not get AMQPConnection not found exception.